# How to move tables from a SQL Server Express to a Standard Edition in another computer with C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I need to take several tables with their data from a SQL Server Express and send them to another computer and create or replace them there in a SQL Server Standard Edition with C#.

I have been looking for a solution and the closest I've found is to recover the tables in `DataTables` or `DataSets` and send them with WCF, but I think I'll lose the indexes and I've read that it's not recommended to send `DataSets` with WCF.

I have also taken a look at Microsoft Sync Framework, but I haven't worked with it and I don't know if it could solve this easily. Another way I've been told to do it is to export the tables and indexes to a SQL script.

My question is: is there an easy way to do this? If not, which is the less painful way to do it?

Edit: Sorry, I forgot to mention that:

-This will happen once or twice a week.

-The machines are not in the same network.

-Eventually, the structure of the tables may change.

Comment: Is both machines are on same network?

Comment: Is this a one-time job, or something recurring (e.g. every week or every month) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it from C#, use SMO (SQL Server Management Objects).

Here you have a sample to tansfer schema and data between two databases.

[Transferring Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162563.aspx)

This project shows how to use it for a table:

[Copy a table using SQL Server Management Objects](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/100614/Copy-a-table-using-SQL-Server-Management-Objects)

Comment: Thanks! The second example with the help of SqlBulkCopy solved it.

Answer (score 2):

You can backup the entire database and restore it in your standard sql server using c#.

Comment: OP states that they only want *some* tables. Of course, you could copy the entire db as described, mount it on the other server and copy tables.

Answer (score 2):

If the databases have network visibility of one another, one way would be to create a [linked server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx) in one of the instances and to [select into](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/t-sql/7126.asp) from one to another.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can backup the database, restore it in the new instance.
2. You can detach it and attach it on the new instance.
3. You can generate a sql script and run it on the new instance.

Comment: The database is huge and I just need a couple of tables. The sql script is a bit complex because I need the entire table with the schema and constraints, not only the rows.

Comment: Generating a script should do it.  Also, The larger SQL instance should be able to connect to the express instance and to an import.

Comment: I've been doing this by creating a publication on the source server and subscribing my server to it. With the SQL Server 2012 licenses change the price of the cheapest version is just too high and it will be replaced with the Express version, so I have to do this with C#. I've already done it with the example that JotaBe gave.